# How do I run cmd as admin from a batch file without clicking yes or no

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, cmd.exe, autorun

How do I run cmd as admin from a batch file without clicking yes or no.   I have figured out how to auto run a bat file from a USB, now all I need to figure out is how to run cmd as admin without clicking yes or no and without a prompt asking for consent.

Plus:  this will be for a admin user

Answer (score 1):

This is a security feature.  Even an administrative user must click OK on the UAC dialog in order to elevate to run something as admin.

You could turn off UAC completely but that would be ill advised.

Comment: I have had this working before but I lost the USB stick so I know it is possible.